# Find current Model ID (has many relationship)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel app that allows users to add reviews to a book.

My Routes are:

```
Route::get('/books/{book}/addreview', 'ReviewController@create'); 
Route::post('books/{book}/review', 'ReviewController@store');
```

My Review controller looks like:

```
public function create(Book $book) {
    return view('/reviews/create');
}

public function store(Book $book){
     $this->validate(request(),[
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required'
     ]);

     Review::create([
        'title'=>request('title'),
        'body'=>request('body'),
        'user_id'=>auth()->id(),
        'book_id'=>$book->id
     ]);
    // return redirect('/books');

}
```

However, I get 'Undefined variable: book' - So I'm not finding the current Book ID. How could I find the current Book ID and pass it to the view?

Comment: this is called route model binding. You are actually binding the model inside the route to get the model instance directly without finding it explicitly using id. Have you added use App\Book; at the top in your controller

Comment: or perhaps you can dd the $book variable what does it returns dd($book);

Comment: Hi yes use App\Book; is in the controller.

Comment: from which function you want to pass the book id to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Review Controller:

```
public function create(Book $book) {
    return view('reviews.create', compact('book'));
}
```

In View:

```
{{ $book->id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send data to view.

```
public function create(Book $book) {
    return view('reviews.create', ['book' => $book]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing anything to the view, you need to explicitly pass data to it so that it can be used:

```
return view('reviews.create', ['book' => $book]);
```

Then in your view, to access the book's ID you can use `$book->id`:

```
Book ID is {{ $book->id }}.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// here I add some custom name to this route which will help to generate
// a corresponding URL in the view by passing this name
// route('routename')

Route::get('/books/{book}/addreview', 'ReviewController@create')->name('review.create'); 
Route::post('/books/{book}/review', 'ReviewController@store')->name('review.store');
```

In your controller which render the `review.create` view you must pass the `$book` that correspond to current model binding in your route like this

```
public function create(Book $book){
    return View::make('reviews.create', ['book' => $book]);
}
```

and in the corresponding view when you create your form you must specify the `action` attribute like this

```
<form action={{ route('review.store', $book)}} method="post">
    {{ csrf_field}}
```